# How can I get an inner value form a JSON array in SWIFT

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I would like to get statusSeverityDescription value from a JSON Array, I am able o get the first section but anything inner I am unable to

this is the array: https://api.tfl.gov.uk/line/mode/tube/status

```
func parseJSONtubes() {  
    let url = NSURL(string: "https://"
    let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)  
    let readableJSON = JSON(data: jsonData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil)  


    for (_,object):(String, JSON) in readableJSON {  
        /  
        let stationName = object["name"].string as String!  
        let statusName = object[0]["lineStatuses"]    ["statusSeverityDescription"].string as String!  
        stationArray.append(stationName)  
        statusArray.append(statusName)  
        /  
        NumberOfRows = stationArray.count  

    }  
    NSLog("\(NumberOfRows)")  
    NSLog("\(stationArray)")  


}
```

I have done something wrong here...... statusName is not displaying anything?!

Comment: @user2924961 you should not download your content synchronously. You should use NSURLSession to download your data asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

It's

```
...
   let stationName = object["name"].stringValue
   let statusName = object["lineStatuses"][0]["statusSeverityDescription"].stringValue
...
```